# onTouch event and Action move android

Tags: android, touch-event

I have ViewPager and I want to move it up and down using onTouch

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getY();
            if (flagMeal)
            {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    xOffset = X;
                    yOffset = Y;
                break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    float x= xOffset - event.getX()  ;
                    float y = yOffset - event.getY()  ;
                    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams p = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) mViewPager.getLayoutParams();
                     p.topMargin = (int) -y ;
                     p.bottomMargin = (int) y ;
                     mViewPager.setLayoutParams(p);
                    // mViewPager.invalidate();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        return true;
    }
```

It's working but the view draw once in correct position and once on the old position it's appears like vibration movement 
did I miss any thing ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the problem 
It was from the `event.getY()` It should be `event.getRawY()` 
But I don't know the reason 
Any explain ?